# Stop Web Essentials 2013 automatically adding compiled CSS file to project

Tags: sass, gruntjs, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials in Visual Studio to compile SASS files locally on save.  However I do not want the generated CSS files to be committed to source control.  I have a Grunt task to compile the SASS when the project is deployed.

My problem is, I can't find a way to stop Web Essentials from adding the CSS files to the project.

- I have tried excluding them from the project but they get re-added on save.
- I have tried adding the files to `gitignore` but it seems to override this and still commit it.

I've looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911817/can-web-essentials-be-configured-to-not-add-css-files-to-visual-studio-project) and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/881)

How to people work around this issue?  I would like to keep compile on save but not commit to source control.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch off the web essentials compilation of SASS and use Task Runner Explorer with grunt and 'watch' task to compile them semi-manually (grunt will compile css on sass files save), after then you can exclude CSS files from project

Comment: tools/options/web essentials/sass - there you should switch all compilation off. then install Task Runner Explorer, and there you can set up compilation of sass on build or debug, without adding them to project. Also uou might add css files to gitignore. Some info about Task Runner Explorer can be found here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx